# Execute instructions over network

Tags: network-programming, executable, remote-server

I was wondering if is there any network protocol which deals with the transmission of executable instructions.

```
Host1                               Host2
SEND(instructions) ---------------> EXECUTE(instructions)
```

Furthermore, is there any software which allows the execution of a program
of Host1 into another remote machine Host2 which has the same architecture?

Comment: Yes, RPC and RMI are examples of such methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. What you're looking for are [RPC (Remote Procedure Call)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) protocols. Some of which, like [SOAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) are open and are implemented by a bunch of different libraries in various languages. Others are closed, or are specific to a single language.